# Can anyone explain how a circular buffer array works?

Tags: data-structures, queues

I'm currently learning about Data Structures and Abstractions and one particular problem has been very confusing to me, and that is the concept of Circular ArrayDeque.

In particular, how can we add or remove elements at the first and last of a circular Arraydeque?

I've learnt a few things so far and listed them down below:

1. There is a head and a tail to the circular array
2. The front and rear values are the same.

However, I'm struggling to understand how this works, so can anyone please take some time off to explain this concept. Every effort would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What research have you done? There are lots of resources that give an overview of it.  e.g., https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97451/what-is-actually-a-circular-array-and-representation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer, https://www.worldofitech.com/deque/

Comment: I don't understand *2. The front and rear values are the same*.

Comment: Have you googled ? This question is very basic and common, and should have lots of answers and illustrations on the web. Good luck.

Comment: @greybeard basically the front of the list and the end of the list is the same since its a circular array. we can set the front value and rear to 0 or -1 or so on....

Comment: You may be mixing up *circular buffer* (e.g. implementation of abstract data type *deque*) and [circular list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circular_linked_list) (ADT).